# logistic regression and binned residual plots: How are the error bounds calculated?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

In Gellman and Hill (in the section on checking and comparing logistic regression), it says that the dotted lines are calculated as 2 sqrt{ p (1-p) / n }  where n is the number of points per bin.
In the binned_residuals function in the performance package in R, we see this:

```
  y <- .recode_to_zero(insight::get_response(model)) - fv
  d <- suppressWarnings(lapply(1:n_bins, function(.x) {
    items <- (1:length(pred))[model.binned == .x]

    sdev <- stats::sd(y[items], na.rm = TRUE)
```

The error bound (sdev) appears to depend on the variation in the residuals per bin. This leads to a rather strange plots, where the error bounds are very tight for some bins, where the residuals had little variation:

[image: example of output of binned_residuals]

Could there be something wrong with the binned_residuals function?